Did Bernie Sanders ever justify his status as a millionaire?
Bernie Sanders has often been criticized about his status as a millionaire, and the apparent hypocrisy of him wanting to "tax the rich" when he is the rich.
Of course there's nothing hypocritical about that if Bernie wants the government to tax himself -- however, it is important to note that since Bernie is in control of his own finances, he doesn't need the government to tax him. He can distribute his wealth into society as he sees fit - yet, he does not, instead choosing to buy 3 homes.
Has Bernie Sanders ever addressed this particular point? That it is apparently hypocritical of him to claim that he wants to tax rich people, i.e. take away their money and give it to people in need, when Bernie himself does not privately do that with his own finances?
There is e.g. nothing preventing Bernie from taking 50 % of his wealth, and just giving it away to poor people. Why does he not do this? Has he ever addressed this?

Clearly an opinion-based question. For all we know, he gives away a portion of his income to match his preferred marginal tax rate on people in his tax bracket. Or perhaps he thinks that only billionaires need higher taxes. Or he wants to be taxed more, but views philanthropy as negative. Or perhaps he thinks that he needs more money than most people because of ongoing health problems or whatever. Or maybe not. We cannot read his mind, so I do not see this question as being useful.

There is nothing hypocritical about earning money and paying what is required while also thinking that the rich should pay more.

I literally don’t get the question. Taxing all rich people versus "taxing" one rich person obviously aren’t the same thing. If there were any argument that he wants to tax everyone but himself, okay, but this looks like it only exists to discredit him. One could construct similar "arguments" of lack of private actions versus calls for government action for just about anyone and anything (If X wants to get rid of illegal aliens, why didn’t he drive them across the border himself?) Please [edit] The question to provide a proper motivation.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Taxation is a systemic approach, while charity is an individual one.
Systems tend to counteract individual approaches -- e.g. if you add more stipends for people to go to university, universities will increase tuition, so the net effect of the stipend is that other students will find it more difficult to attend.
The same goes for redistributing personal wealth. Without systemic change, the effects would be immediately counteracted, possibly also creating a dependency on continued charity as the baseline rises.

I think there are some very broad statements here based on a clear-cut distinction between individual and systemic economic factors that seems questionable. E.g. does the price of college tuition really "know" the difference between the government giving out a stipend of $1 to everyone (systemic, I guess?) and giving out a stipend of 100,000 to one person in 100,000 (individual, I guess?) if the universities' income increases by the same amount? Maybe, maybe not, but I think the assertions need extensive support from research if the answer is to be good.

Also, you know, doesn't really establish either that (a) Bernie Sanders is paying less than he "should" according to his own arguments or (b) that this is his reasoning. In fact, contra both ideas, he has actually donated hundreds of thousands to charity from his individual income, plus all the proceeds from a single book, which probably amount to much more.

The government handing out stipends to everyone would still be compensated for, so this would not be a good strategy for a government. The systemic approach is to build state universities.

Bernie Sanders has introduced (sponsored) or cosponsored many taxation bills which can be found here (https://www.congress.gov/member/bernard-sanders/S000033?q=%7B%22subject%22%3A%22Taxation%22%7D).
Among these are S.1173 - Paying a Fair Share Act of 2023, which requires "individual taxpayer whose adjusted gross income exceeds $1 million pay a minimum tax rate of 30% of the excess of the taxpayer's adjusted gross income over the taxpayer's modified charitable contribution deduction for the taxable year"
Since as you say he is a millionaire, then it follows from these facts that he doesn't have this hypocrisy as while he is rich, he is pushing for laws to tax the rich. QED

The question is not great, but if you are going to answer it anyway, it already recognizes that he advocates for higher taxes on wealthy individuals. The assertion—which may not be factually correct—is that he choose to keep a larger share of his income than he says he "should" give back to society. This answer does not address that.

Also, it does not establish that Bernie's gross yearly income ever is or was above USD 1,000,000. He has described himself as a millionaire, but that's about wealth, not income. In point of fact, he earned about USD 2,500,000 over 10 years from his book, making it unlikely that he exceeded USD 1 million in a given year even with his congressional salary of USD 174,000, so this law would likely not have applied to him in any year.

@Obie2.0: would need better [per year] data to be sure. Some political 'bestsellers'  sell a lot in one year and not much thereafter. "Most sales occur soon after a book hits the shelves and gradually peter out." https://www.gsb.stanford.edu/insights/surprising-impact-bestseller-list

@timetakesitstoll - It's true, and I did actually go looking and found that he allegedly made over 1 million in a single year. Which is possibly why he decided to donate all the royalties from "The Speech," in the end. Despite the people saying "No matter how much money Bernie makes, he morally need not give it away," the evidence suggests that he might think differently....
